# Log4j2 default rollover strategy deleting new log files

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am trying to configure log4j2 to use a rollingFileAppender but it is not working as I expect it to.

Here is my current code for configuring log4j2 which is a slightly modified version of what is found here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Configurator under the rollingFileAppender example  ( I have also used the example given there without modifications with similar results)

```
   LoggerContext ctx;
   public Logger logger;


    ConfigurationBuilder< BuiltConfiguration > builder =
    ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    builder.setStatusLevel(Level.ALL);
    builder.setConfigurationName("RollingBuilder");
// create the console appender
    AppenderComponentBuilder appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("Stdout", "CONSOLE").addAttribute("target",
            ConsoleAppender.Target.SYSTEM_OUT);
    appenderBuilder.add(builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").
            addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n%throwable"));
    builder.add( appenderBuilder );

    LayoutComponentBuilder layoutBuilder = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout")
            .addAttribute("pattern", "%d [%t] %-5level: %msg%n");
    ComponentBuilder triggeringPolicy = builder.newComponent("Policies")
            .addComponent(builder.newComponent("CronTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("schedule", "0 * * * * ?"))
            .addComponent(builder.newComponent("SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy").addAttribute("size", "100M"));
    ComponentBuilder defaultStrat = builder.newComponent("DefaultRolloverStrategy")
            .addAttribute("min", 10)
            .addAttribute("max", 20);
    appenderBuilder = builder.newAppender("rolling", "RollingFile")
            .addAttribute("fileName", "targetTest/rollingTEST.log")
            .addAttribute("filePattern", "targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-%d{yy-dd-MM-kk-mm}-test.log.gz") 
            .addAttribute("immediateFlush", false)
            .addComponent(defaultStrat)
            .add(layoutBuilder)
            .addComponent(triggeringPolicy);
    builder.add(appenderBuilder);


// create the new logger
    builder.add( builder.newLogger( "TestLogger", Level.ALL )
            .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) )   );
            //.addAttribute( "additivity", false ) );

    builder.add( builder.newRootLogger( Level.ALL )
            .add( builder.newAppenderRef( "rolling" ) ) );


    this.ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());

    this.logger = ctx.getLogger("TestLogger");
```

What I expect this to do: log to the `rollingTest.log` file, then every minute it should archive that into a `rollingTest-16-21-07-11-30.log.gz` file and then start logging again in the `rollingTest.log` file, until a rollover happens another minute after that.

What actually happens: Logs get logged to `rollingTest.log` and after a minute of starting my server the first rollover attempts to happen, but the file is deleted and then after that a rollover attempts to happen every second. At this point if I try to log anything more, it will try to archive it in a new file, but that new file will also be deleted.

Here are the logs of this happening:

```
2016-07-21 15:20:00,009 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 6.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:00,030 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:00,042 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE Renamed file /Users/Source/targetTest/rollingTEST.log to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log with Files.move
2016-07-21 15:20:00,042 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async GzCompressAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, deleteSource=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:01,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:01,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-19-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:02,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending deleting targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz at low index 10: all slots full.
2016-07-21 15:20:02,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending executing 9 of 10: FileRenameAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, renameEmptyFiles=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:02,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz -> /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:02,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to copy file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:03,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:03,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:04,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:04,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:05,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:05,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:06,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:06,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:06,007 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE Renamed file /Users/Source/targetTest/rollingTEST.log to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log with Files.move
2016-07-21 15:20:06,007 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async GzCompressAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, deleteSource=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:07,001 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending deleting targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz at low index 10: all slots full.
2016-07-21 15:20:07,002 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending executing 9 of 10: FileRenameAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, renameEmptyFiles=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:07,002 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz -> /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:07,002 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to copy file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:08,003 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:08,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:08,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE Renamed file /Users/Source/targetTest/rollingTEST.log to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log with Files.move
2016-07-21 15:20:08,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async GzCompressAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, deleteSource=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:09,007 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending deleting targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz at low index 10: all slots full.
2016-07-21 15:20:09,009 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending executing 9 of 10: FileRenameAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, renameEmptyFiles=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:09,009 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz -> /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:09,010 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to copy file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:10,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:10,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:11,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:11,005 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
2016-07-21 15:20:11,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE Renamed file /Users/Source/targetTest/rollingTEST.log to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log with Files.move
2016-07-21 15:20:11,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async GzCompressAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, deleteSource=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:12,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending deleting targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz at low index 10: all slots full.
2016-07-21 15:20:12,006 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending executing 9 of 10: FileRenameAction[targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz, renameEmptyFiles=true]
2016-07-21 15:20:12,007 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to move file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz -> /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:12,007 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 ERROR Unable to copy file /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz to /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException /Users/Source/targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log.gz
2016-07-21 15:20:13,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 0.0 milliseconds
2016-07-21 15:20:13,004 Log4j2-Log4j2Scheduled-1 DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[targetTest/rollingTEST.log to targetTest/archive/rollingTEST-16-21-07-15-20-test.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]
```

If I put a `%i` argument into the file name then my new files will not be deleted, but the rollover process still fires every second after the initial one has completed and I end up with a new file for every log event I send to the logger.

Edit: I just tried this using an XML configuration file instead of the programmatic approach above with similar results. Here is the configuration file I used:

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="target/logfile.log"
                 filePattern="target/archive/logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss}.log" >
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <CronTriggeringPolicy schedule="0 * * * * ?"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="TestLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

When I had a `%i` in the file name the rollover triggered every second from the moment my server started and created a new file for each log event sent to it.

When I didn't have a `%i` in the file name I had two experiences:

- the first was a rollover every second after the initial event and a new file for every logging event
- the second was what I described above where my roll over files got deleted after they were created. This also triggered a rollover every second after the initial event.

Comment: Can you specify which Log4j 2 version you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.6.2

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be addressed in the lastest versions. Related issues,
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1480

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1548

I have update to version 2.8.2 and no longer seeing this error.